# What is the easiest way to retrieve a nested organization hierarchy from a database (nosql or relational)?

Tags: database

So I've been reviewing database techniques for SQL on how to best store hierarchical data. The consensus seemed to be nested sets.

However, it doesn't appear to me that it easily answers the question "give me the entire hierarchy". Regardless of my query, I will always be returned a table. So in order to get a tree-like structure, I'll always have to do some sort of messy parsing of multiple query results.

If I have hierarchical data, is there some way I could get a nested return set of all children of an element using only one query? If so how should I setup my nosql/relational database to do it? Database choice doesn't matter. Just whatever can do this query the easiest.

Example. Give me Steve's descendants:

```
Mary: {
  Steve: {
    Paul: {
      Nick: {}
    }
    Emily: {}
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  Steve: {
    Paul: {
      Nick: {}
    }
    Emily: {}
  }
```

EDIT: Regarding "How should I set up my database." I was more trying to point out that anything regardings schemas,ontologies,etc. is fair game (within practical reason). I am unaware of something that could give me a query result like this in one line given anything I know, so I didn't want to put any restrictions.

Comment: "how should I setup my nosql/relational database " - pick one.... "Database choice doesn't matter" - of course it does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while your question is exceptionally broad, I have wrestled with this problem and want to share some of my lessons learned.

> So I've been reviewing database techniques for SQL on how to best store hierarchical data. The consensus seemed to be nested sets.

First off, I would challenge that consensus, for several reasons, the biggest of which is "what do you do if your set is extremely large?" This model completely breaks down under that assumption.

My databases model building automation systems. One or two BAS systems is no big deal, but hundreds or thousands of buildings, each building with thousands of objects, can be overwhelming to simple SQL databases.

I've tried HierarchyID and found it to be cumbersome and impossible to maintain.
I've tried recursive CTEs in SQL and found their performance to degrade exponentially as table size increases.

Ultimately, I found the simplest method is to store the individual objects in a flat table along with a reference to their parent object, then to have an external process index the parent-children relationships. `Couchbase` does this automatically in its view system.  It is still expensive to query for the entire hierarchy, but this problem can be solved in a variety of ways.

So, a broad question gets a broad answer. Do you have more specific questions you would like to ask?

Comment: The goal was simplicity. I have a parent-child table of organization ids. I want to get any subtree as easily as possible. I also want it to be able to translate easily to a useful data structure for displaying in a UI (e.g. a json file since many frameworks can use that as a model for a web view). For my current solution, I was doing a depth first search and doing thousands of query for "get children of this organization id" repetitively and combining into a json structure. I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Comment: Size is also not a concern. There are maybe 3000 organization ids. Each of which is a primary key to a table with at most 10 columns.

Comment: Well there is always an easier way...

Comment: You make it sound like its obvious but it isn't to me.

Comment: I'm speaking in general terms, it really is difficult to devise a simple solution to a problem when I don't know all of your specifications.

Comment: I gave little specification because I wanted to give whoever was helping me the freedom to use whatever schema, databse, etc. they wanted. Whatever made the task the easiest to understand. Currently I have a hierarchy table with two columns, child and parent. What is the easiest way to get a subtree in a json-like format. By easiest, I mean fewest queries and quick parsing of the result set.

Comment: I think easiest would be to use a database that stores native JSON. Look at elasticsearch.